# 'first' is not valid at this position expecting EOF, AS etc

Tags: mysql

```
use tutorial;

CREATE TABLE people (
    'first' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    middle CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    'last' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    sex VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    birthday DATETIME NOT NULL,
    state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    );
```

//side note, I am extremely new, just trying to learn, and I came across this error and was unsure of how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql, if you want to use reserved words as column names, you must enclose them in backticks, not single quotes.  You also appear to have reversed the order of the `id INT` and `PRIMARY KEY` lines, leaving a comma missing and an extra comma.

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    `first` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    middle CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `last` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    sex VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    birthday DATETIME NOT NULL,
    state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )

    );
```